# invalid length parameter passed to the left or substring function charindex

Tags: t-sql, charindex, instr

**I need to translate the Oracle SQL-code**

```
select URL, TO_NUMBER(NVL( substr(URL,INSTR(URL,'pageId=') + 7, INSTR(URL,'&')- (INSTR(URL,'pageId=') + 7) )  , substr(URL,INSTR(URL,'pageId=') + 7) )) PageId
            from remotelink
           WHERE INSTR(URL,'pageId')>0;
```

to T-SQL (MS SQL-Server 2012)

My translated Code looks like this:

```
select URL, CAST(ISNULL( substring(URL,CHARINDEX('pageId=', URL) + 7, CHARINDEX('&', URL)- (CHARINDEX('pageId=', URL) + 7) )  , substring(URL,CHARINDEX('pageId=', URL) + 7, datalength(URL)) )AS numeric) PageId
            from JIRA_TEST.jiraschema.remotelink
           WHERE CHARINDEX('pageId', URL) >0
```

I receive the error

*"invalid length parameter passed to the left or substring function"*

Any hints?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Actually, sample data and expected results would be a much better help for us to help you solve your problem. Please [edit] your question to follow the guidlines in the first three paragraphs of the [tsql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info).